# How to batch open txt files and save each with Sublime in linux command line?

Tags: save, command-line-interface, sublimetext3, batch-processing

How to command Sublime from linux command line?

I know how to open file in background but not how to call save function?

I have some character issues which Sublime seems to fix and therefore I'd like to run a batch of files through Sublime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the available commands are listed on the reference section of docs:
https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/commands.html